# How To Add Sidebar on Telescope

Tags: telescope

Im using Telescope(meteor) for my site project. The default telescope theme only have single column. How can i create sidebar (another column, so it will be two column website) at the right side ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should create a package that holds your sidebar template with the required markups.

Then identify the zone you wish to add the sidebar to.

Preferably to contentTop. Since it is displayed in all pages. Be aware of flexbox layout that you might need to tweak.
e.g

```
Telescope.modules.add("contentTop", {
      template: 'sidebar', 
      order: 0
});
```

Comment: how to do that ? can you guide me step by step ?